# What is the meaning of the VirtualBox USB device address?

Tags: usb, virtualbox

VirtualBox has a command line interface [VBoxManage](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html), and one command lists the USB devices on the host: `VBoxManage list usbhost`. Output is like this:

```
UUID:               16041f16-b030-449c-b823-a915b62918d6
VendorId:           0x0a12 (0A12)
ProductId:          0x0001 (0001)
Revision:           72.57 (7257)
Port:               2
USB version/speed:  0/Full
Manufacturer:       Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd
Product:            Bluetooth
Address:            p=0x0001;v=0x0a12;s=0x00025f48aad7b0d5;l=0x14200000
Current State:      Available
```

I'd like to understand the meaning of the address. `p` is obviously USB product ID. Similarly, `v` is USB vendor ID. What are `s` and `l`?

Answer (score 0):

**s** is the serial number of the USB.

**l** is the Location ID.